# How can I activate google assistant without saying OK google or Hey Google on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

Im working on project on Auto turning the car turn signal when google asisstant hear the hotword from google maps for example it detect "turn left" so it can trigger the left signal and "turn right" it can trigger the right signal.
The problem that i face is i dont know how to deactivate ok google hotword from hotword.py. I want the google assistant always on without saying ok google or hey google. Hope someone can help me what should i edit or add in hotword.py code.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the [Google Assistant Service](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/) which allows you as a developer to initiate a request to the Assistant programmatically with either audio or text input.